# Reassigning a pointer when the object it is pointing to is deleted by an instance of another class

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, dangling-pointer

I am creating a Tower Defence game mockup where enemies attempt to cross the screen before they are destroyed.

Pointers to dynamically allocated Enemy objects are stored in a vector inside an EnemyManager class that controls how they spawn and despawn. When the health of an Enemy reaches zero the EnemyManager deletes it using `delete`, and also `erase`s the pointer.

I have a BulletTower object that is meant to lock on to a single Enemy and shoot until it is destroyed, then lock onto another. This requires a pointer to an Enemy object, but if the Enemy dies and is deleted by the EnemyManager, the pointer is dangling.

There doesn't seem to be a way the pointer can tell if the enemy being locked on to is destroyed. I looked into smart pointers, but it seems like shared pointers wouldn't work given that the enemies are being manually deleted when their health reaches zero.

Comment: If you store _shared pointers_ into `EnemyManager`, they you can create a _weak pointer_ for a particular `Enemy` locked by a `BulletTower`. That weak pointer then allows you to find out whether that enemy still exists or not (and does not prevent the enemy being killed-deleted).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But doesn't making a `shared_ptr` to the Enemy objects prevent me from deleting them manually when their health reaches zero?

Edit: Or is the solution to `reset` the shared pointer when the health reaches zero, causing the object to be deleted?

Comment: Instead of delete them manually, simply erase the shared pointer from the `EnemyManager`. Deleter of shared pointer will delete the enemy for you. I don't know the details since you are not showing any code how enemies are stored in a manager (possibly in a vector or a list?).

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! (I did mention they were stored in a vector in the post, I would provide code but there wasn't much that I could have added to clarify past what is there)

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that information, my bad. Anyway, as you remove the shared pointer from a vector, the pointed-to enemy gets deleted automatically.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So to clarify, to remove the shared pointer from the vector, I would use `std::vector::erase`? And to check the weak pointer in the BulletTower class, I would use `std::weak_ptr::expired`?

Comment: Yes. Note that a vector might not be the most efficient container here, since the erasure of an element has linear complexity (all the elements past the erased one needs to be shifted one place left). However, if you don't rely on a particular order of enemies, you can first swap the killed enemy with the last one in a vector (then its erasure will have constant complexity). Or, you can switch to a list.

Comment: You might have a design problem. Let the EnemyManager, and only the EnemyManager manage the ennemies. The BulletTower would than ask the EnemyMa ager for a pointer to an enemy (with some ID or smth). If the EnemyManager doesn't find the enemy, it could give a pointer to another enemy.

Comment: @MFnx with `n` towers and `m` enemies, you end up with `O(n*log(m))` unnecessary lookups each frame, no good design for realtime applications

Comment: @fdan if you use hashtables (unordered_map for instance), it shouldn't be too expensive, should it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Weak pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) could perhaps do the job.

Also, instead of giving a Enemy pointer to BulletTower, you could give a function or object which would return the current locked enemy if alive, or return a new one.

Comment: The second suggestion wouldn't work since the BulletTower decides which Enemy to lock on to (should've clarified on my post), but weak pointers did the job!

Answer (score 1):

You can store the pointer to the actual `Enemy` object in a variable. And have a pointer to this pointer variable for the `BulletTower` objects. When the `Enemy` is killed, the `EnemyManager` can change the variable to `nullptr` and the `BulletTower` object can check this fact, through the pointer it has.

So essentially, the `BulletTower` is locking on to the pointer variable and not the `Enemy` object directly.

**OR**

Maintain a count of how many `BulletTower` objects have locked on to the `Enemy`. Don't delete the `Enemy` unless that count has become 0. For `BulletTower` take the lock off when the energy has become 0 and decrement the lock count.